# How to send an email in Xamarin Android using variables of radio buttons?

Tags: c#, android, email, xamarin

Hi I'm doing an applicative and it has an Send E-mail button.

So on that button I want to send some variables that will recieve the value of some RadioGroups.

I did some "If/ElseIf" to allow the user to pick just one RadioGroup and then to send an email (so far so good) to the person that will be in a spinner.

But when I try to choose 2 RadioGroups or more when I click on the "Send E-mail Button" Idk why, the program just pass the value of the last clicked button and don't pass all values that I selected like the following images[Email Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1Guz.png)
[image: App Screen]

**So how can I send 2 or more variables on the e-mail**

Here is the code

```
    using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Collections;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Auth0.OidcClient;
using Android.Content;
using IdentityModel.OidcClient;
using Android.Graphics;
using System.Net;
using System;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Text.Method;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace whirlpoolgratitudeapp
{
    [Activity(Label = "whirlpoolgratitudeapp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    [IntentFilter(
    new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataScheme = "whirlpoolgratitudeapp.whirlpoolgratitudeapp",
    DataHost = "lucasmsantos.auth0.com",
    DataPathPrefix = "/android/whirlpoolgratitudeapp.whirlpoolgratitudeapp/callback")]

    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        private ArrayList enderecos;
        TextView queroreconhecer;
        TextView crie;
        TextView conquiste;
        TextView entregue;
        TextView viva;
        TextView comentar;
        EditText comentário;
        Spinner spinner;
        ArrayAdapter adapter;
        RadioGroup rdgcrie;
        RadioGroup rdgconquiste;
        RadioGroup rdgentregue;
        RadioGroup rdgviva;
        Button enviar;
        private Auth0Client client;
        private AuthorizeState authorizeState;
        ProgressDialog progress;
        List<RadioGroup> lista = new List<RadioGroup>();
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            if (progress != null)
            {
                progress.Dismiss();

                progress.Dispose();
                progress = null;
            }
        }

        protected override async void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            base.OnNewIntent(intent);

            var loginResult = await client.ProcessResponseAsync(intent.DataString, authorizeState);

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (loginResult.IsError)
            {
                sb.AppendLine($"An error occurred during login: {loginResult.Error}");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.AppendLine($"ID Token: {loginResult.IdentityToken}");
                sb.AppendLine($"Access Token: {loginResult.AccessToken}");
                sb.AppendLine($"Refresh Token: {loginResult.RefreshToken}");

                sb.AppendLine();

                sb.AppendLine("-- Claims --");
                foreach (var claim in loginResult.User.Claims)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine($"{claim.Type} = {claim.Value}");
                }
            }


        }

        private async void LoginButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {


            progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progress.SetTitle("Log In");
            progress.SetMessage("Please wait while redirecting to login screen...");
            progress.SetCancelable(false); // disable dismiss by tapping outside of the dialog
            progress.Show();

            // Prepare for the login
            authorizeState = await client.PrepareLoginAsync();

            // Send the user off to the authorization endpoint
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(authorizeState.StartUrl);
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions
            {
                Domain = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.auth0_domain),
                ClientId = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.auth0_client_id),
                Activity = this
            });
            //preenche o arraylist com os dados
            GetEmails();
            //cria a instância do spinner declarado no arquivo Main
            spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spnDados);
            //cria textview
            queroreconhecer = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtReconhecer);
            crie = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCrie);
            conquiste = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtConquiste);
            entregue = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtEntregue);
            viva = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtViva);
            comentar = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtComentário);
            comentário = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edtComentario);
            rdgcrie = FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.rdgCrie);
            rdgconquiste = FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.rdgConquiste);
            rdgentregue = FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.rdgEntregue);
            rdgviva = FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.rdgViva);
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, enderecos);
            spinner.Adapter = adapter;
            spinner.ItemSelected += Spinner_ItemSelected;
            enviar = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            enviar.Click += enviar_Click;
            lista.Add(rdgconquiste);
            lista.Add(rdgcrie);
            lista.Add(rdgentregue);
            lista.Add(rdgviva);
            void GetEmails()
            {
                enderecos = new ArrayList();
                enderecos.Add("Escolha um colaborador");
                enderecos.Add("alexandre_bonfim@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("alexandre_t_pires@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("ana_carolina_simoes @whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("ana_claudia_s_belarmino@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("andre_costa@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("andre_l_teixeira@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("andreza_a_valle@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("anna_carolina_b_ferreira@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("bruno_b_souza@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("bruno_c_castanho@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("bruno_s_lombardero@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("caio_c_sacoman@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("carla_sedin@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("cassia_r_nascimento@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("celia_r_araujo@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("cesar_leandro_de_oliveira@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("daniel_b_szortyka@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("denis_caciatori@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("elisabete_c_ferreira@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("erick_c_senzaki@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("erika_g_souza@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("fabiana_monteiro@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("fernando_v_santos@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("gabriel_roveda@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("herivelto_alves_jr@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("jefferson_s_pecanha@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("josiane_a_teles@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("juliana_g_saito@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("juliano_ventola@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("leonardo_l_costa@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("leonardo_r_silva@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("lucas_m_santos@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("luiz_perea@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("norma_raphaeli@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("patricia_f_prates@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("priscila_l_dattilo@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("priscila_m_konte@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("reider_a_bernucio@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("renato_occhiuto@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("ricardo_a_fernandes@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("ricardo_matos_campaneruti @whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("rogerio_pagotto@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("ruben_c_anacleto@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("taise_azevedo@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("vinicius_marques_assis@whirlpool.com");
                enderecos.Add("wanderly_t_limeira@whirlpool.com");
            }// fim getEmails

            void Spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
            {

                Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
                string toast = string.Format("Colaborador selecionado: {0}", spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position));
                string welcome = "Bem vindo ao aplicativo de agradecimento";
                if (toast.Equals("Escolha um colaborador") )
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, welcome, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show();

                }

            }
            void showbox(string msg)
            {
                var progressDialog = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "Mensagem", msg, true);
                new System.Threading.Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
                {
                    //LOAD METHOD TO GET ACCOUNT INFO
                    RunOnUiThread(() => Toast.MakeText(this, msg, ToastLength.Long).Show());
                    //HIDE PROGRESS DIALOG
                    RunOnUiThread(() => progressDialog.Dismiss());
                    RunOnUiThread(() => progressDialog.Hide());
                })).Start();

            }

            void enviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    RadioButton rdbgrupo1 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgconquiste.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                    RadioButton rdbgrupo2 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgcrie.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                    RadioButton rdbgrupo3 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgviva.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                    RadioButton rdbgrupo4 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgentregue.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                    int RadioGroupIsChecked(RadioGroup radioGroup)
                    {
                        //-1 means empty selection
                        return radioGroup.CheckedRadioButtonId;
                    }

                    //When user doesn't check a radio button, show a Toast
                    if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) == -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) == -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) == -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) == -1)
                    {
                        string excecao = "Ao menos um botão deve ser selecionado e o comentário deve ser preenchido";
                        Toast.MakeText(this, excecao, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String emailescolhido = spinner.SelectedItem.ToString();

                        if (emailescolhido == "Escolha um colaborador abaixo")
                        {
                            string excecao = "Por favor, escolha um colaborador";
                            Toast.MakeText(this, excecao, ToastLength.Long).Show();

                        }

                        else { 
                        String campocomentario = comentário.Text;
                            string emailchefe = "acursio_maia@whirlpool.com";
                        var email = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
                        //send to
                        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraEmail,
                        new string[] { "" + emailescolhido });
                            //if (emailescolhido == "andreza_a_valle" || emailescolhido.Equals("lucas_m_santos") || emailescolhido == "erika_g_souza@whirlpool.com" || emailescolhido == "caio_c_sacoman")
                            //{
                            //    //cc to
                            //    email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraCc,
                            //    new string[] { "comite_clima_ti@whirlpool.com" + emailchefe });
                            //}
                        //cc to
                        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraCc,
                        new string[] { "comite_clima_ti@whirlpool.com" + emailchefe });
                        //subject
                        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, "SABIA QUE VOCÊ FOI RECONHECIDO?");
                        //content
                        if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) != -1)
                            {
                                email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                                "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo1.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo2.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo3.Text + " e " + rdbgrupo4.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                            }

                            else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) != -1)
                            {
                                email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                                "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo1.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                            }
                            else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) != -1)
                            {
                                email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                                "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo2.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                            }
                            else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) != -1)
                            {
                                email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                                "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo3.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                            }
                            else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) != -1)
                            {
                                email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                                "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo4.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                            }
                            else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) != -1)
                            {
                                email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                                "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo1.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo2.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                            }

                            else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) != -1)
                            {
                                email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                                "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo1.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo4.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                            }
                            else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) != -1)
                            {
                                email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                                "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo2.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo3.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                            }
                            else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) != -1)
                            {
                                email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                                "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo2.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo4.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                            }
                            else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) != -1)
                            {
                                email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                                "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo3.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo4.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                            }
                            else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) != -1)
                            {
                                email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                                "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " +rdbgrupo1.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo2.Text + " e " + rdbgrupo3.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                            }
                            else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) != -1)
                            {
                                email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                                "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo1.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo2.Text + " e " + rdbgrupo4.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                            }
                            else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) != -1)
                            {
                                email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                                "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo1.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo3.Text + " e " + rdbgrupo3.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                            }
                            else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) != -1)
                            {
                                email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                                "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo2.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo3.Text + " e " + rdbgrupo4.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                            }
                            email.SetType("message/rfc822");
                        StartActivity(email);
                        Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        alertdialog.SetTitle("Confirmação de envio");
                        alertdialog.SetMessage("Email enviado com sucesso");
                        alertdialog.SetNeutralButton("Ok", delegate {
                            alertdialog.Dispose();
                        });
                        alertdialog.Show();
                    }
                    }


                }


                catch (Java.Lang.Exception ex)
                {
                    showbox(ex.Message);

                } } }



            }

        }
```

Comment: Just a comment. Update your original post to remove the email addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, I think you tried to use a click event of `Button` to get checked `RadioButton` of each `RadioGroup`, then for example if the layout is like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <RadioGroup
      android:id="@+id/group1"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="This is group 1" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio11"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="radio1" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio12"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="radio2" />
  </RadioGroup>
  <RadioGroup
      android:id="@+id/group2"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="This is group 2" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio21"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="radio3" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio22"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="radio4" />
  </RadioGroup>
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/checkBtn"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:text="get checked radiobutton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You can code like this:

```
private string result;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create your application here
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);

    RadioGroup group1 = FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.group1);
    RadioGroup group2 = FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.group2);

    Button enviar = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.checkBtn);
    enviar.Click += (sender, e) =>
    {
        var itemOfGroup1 = group1.CheckedRadioButtonId;
        var itemOfGroup2 = group2.CheckedRadioButtonId;

        if (itemOfGroup1 != -1) //if one of the group radio is checked
        {
            var radiobtn1 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(itemOfGroup1);
            result = "group1:" + radiobtn1.Text;
        }

        if (itemOfGroup2 != -1)
        {
            var radiobtn2 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(itemOfGroup2);
            result = result + " group2:" + radiobtn2.Text;
        }

        //if there're more groups, codes are the same, for example: result = result + "group3: "+ radiaobtn3.Text;

        var email = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
        email.PutExtra("message", result);
        //more email relative codes goes here
    };
}
```

You don't need to have that complex logic, and I only used a simple string to combine all `Text` of checked `RadioButton` in the variable value `result`, you should be able to change the format of this string. Good luck.